# PHP code in SQL displayed in page

Tags: php, sql

I want to be able to store PHP code in an SQL Database and display that whenever it is called. I don't want to use include and make loads of files. I want to be able to just put them all in SQL and call them when I want. How can I do this?

I have

```
$GETPAGE = "SELECT PA_CONTENT from pages where PA_NAME = '$page'";
$GETPAGE2= mysql_query($GETPAGE);
$GETPAGE3= mysql_fetch_array($GETPAGE2);
echo $GETPAGE3[PA_CONTENT];
```

but it echo's it out visible. Should I replace echo for something else?

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: If you're using eval() as a substitute of include(),just to avoid using files, you should change your mind. And instead of eval() you might want to consider a templating engine, like Twig or Smarty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to execute code that's in strings.  Just make sure that you **absolutely trust** the code that's being run - it will run any PHP code it's given, so it could do malicious things if it's so instructed.

Comment: Thanks Alot, shoulda kinda looked there first!

Comment: The PHP Manual is a tremendous resource.  Be sure to read the dire warnings about eval() - it could cause some serious problems, so think it through and make sure it's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can evaluate a string as code by using `eval()`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

BUT this is not recommended, see also the warning on that page:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: and "user-provided data" can mean "via previously stored SQL insert."